# TestFlight "testers" VS App Store "users"

Tags: app-store, testflight

When we will upgrade our app from TestFlight to App Store

Our 87 testers will be translated to 87 downloads?

Answer (score 0):

Yes they will, when testers install the final released app they will be counted as downloads.